# JSON object with multiple arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

At the moment I have multiple arrays inside an object containing different pieces of data.

The issue is that the JSON is invalid and I am not sure who to correct it.

Here is my current code:

```
{
    "cars": {
        [{
            "model": 'test'
        }],
        [{
            "model": 'test2'
        }]
    }
};
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I think you want just one array, with multiple objects inside it: `{"cars": [{"model":"test"},{"model":"test2"}]}` is valid JSON.

Comment: And if I'm not mistaking, only double quotes are valid json

Comment: JSON is based on `key:value` pairs.  Your second array is not a part of a pair.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use key:value pairs and remove that semicolon.

```
{
    "cars": [
        {
            "model": "test"
        },
        {
            "model": "test2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Then once you parse your JSON and assign it to a variable, e.g. `jsonVar`, you can loop over the array `jsonVar.cars` to get each dictionary, which has `model` property.

More [examples](https://json.org/example.html) of correctly formatted JSON.

Finally, [this](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) JSON validator can provide helpful hints on incorrectly formatted JSON.